# MVC 5 application Deployment on IIS7 getting error 404.8

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5, web-deployment, asp.net-4.5

I have created a MVC5 Web Application and tried to deploy on IIS7 on a separate machine having windows 2007 . everything is set ok but when I am Browsing it its giving

> ```
>  404.8 The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section
> ```

please Suggest something .

I have tried it by publish also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Solved by installing **.Net 4.5 framework** separately I have missed it previously .
for my Other Friends who are facing same problem . you should have these .

- entity framework
- razor framework
- .Net framework 4.5

Answer (score 3):

By default IIS will reject requests where the path contains "bin", "app_code", "app_data", and a few other reserved names.  See http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering (section "Filter Out Hidden Segments") for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.Just do the following steps resolved my issue.

- Go to IIS manager
- Select your web site
- Double click on the Request filtering icon under IIS.
- Right click the file that error raised and remove it.